# Spikes impact on time series stationarity

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, outliers, stationarity, seasonality

I have a demand time series that are highly impacted by promotion (spikes). 
Do spikes violate the assumptions of stationarity?
Can we apply the KPSS test or ADF to test whether the series is stationary or not?

Answer (score 0):

Promotions are an *intervention* decided by the seller, so presumably you know the dates when it was applied.  So you should model them as interventions. It doesn't make much sense to consider the sales process as stationary when including the spikes (although it might be so, formally, if the interventions was applied at random times.)  But it might well be an underlying demand process which is stationary, but then the sales are decided not only by demand, but also by the promotions.

So you could use a stationary model of the pre-intervention process, and then add the interventions to the model.

But since you *know* the source of non-stationarity, using hypothesis test to test for stationarity does not make sense for me.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. Since I know the promotion times I can estimate a baseline and test the baseline for stationarity. That would tell me whether the demand is stationary or not. right?

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable